# .htaccess redirect all subdomains to external URL

Tags: .htaccess

So I have a website with about 50 subdomains created. I want them **all** pointed to an external URL.

Ideally, I'd like ANYTHING written before the domain name to be redirected.

Meaning: xxxa.domain.com gets redirected. Same with 12213123123.domain.com.

To an external URL.

How do I do this using .htaccess? I've tried numerous code examples, but none of them work.

Comment: Hi there, could you give the code examples you've tried?

Comment: @Michelle, here's the latest: RewriteEngine On
# allow www.example.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com
# any other host/subdomain gets redirected
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.*)\.example\.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://somewhere-else.com/ [R,END]

This does not work.

Comment: Please don't post additional details in comments, it is impossible to read it and does not help. There is an "edit" link below your question. _Use it_ ...